# How do I mock a string response in a Unit Test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Here's what I have in my test so far:

```
[TestFixture]
public class IndividualMovieTests
{
    [Test]
    public void WebClient_Should_Download_From_Correct_Endpoint()
    {
        const string correctEndpoint = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/{movie-id}.json?apikey={your-api-key}";
        ApiEndpoints.Endpoints["IndividualMovie"].ShouldEqual(correctEndpoint);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Movie_Information_Is_Loaded_Correctly()
    {
        Tomato tomato = new Tomato("t4qpkcsek5h6vgbsy8k4etxdd");
        var movie = tomato.FindMovieById(9818);
        movie.Title.ShouldEqual("Gone With The Wind");
    }
}
```

My FIndMovieById method goes online and fetches a JSON result, and that means it sort of breaks the principle **behind** unit testing. I have a feeling I have to mock this string response, but I don't really know how to approach this.

How would **you** approach this particular unit testing?

Comment: Have you considered using a mocking framework? It could be quite useful if you're going to be making a lot of unit tests for methods that make external API calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second `[Test]`, I would suggest not focusing on a specific return value from your `FindMovieById` method, unless you truly want to test that your given inputs should always result in "Gone With the Wind".  The test that you have seems to be a very specific test case in which a specific input number results in a specific output, which is something that may or may not change when running against your actual database.  Also, since you're not going to be testing against the actual web service, doing this kind of validation is basically self-serving - you're not really testing anything.  Instead, focus on testing how the Tomato class handles validation of the argument (if at all), and that the Tomato class actually invokes the service to get the return value.  Rather than testing specific inputs and outputs, test the behavior of the class, so that if someone changes it in the future, the test should break to alert them that they may have broken working functionality.

For example, if you have input validation, you could test that your Tomato class throws an exception if an invalid input is detected.

Assuming that your Tomato class has some sort of web client functionality for requesting and retrieving the results, you could plug in some stub implementations of the actual web code, or mocked implementations to ensure that Tomato is in fact calling the appropriate web client code to request and process the response.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you might not have to mock to test you code. For example, if you are just testing that you can deserialize JSON into a `Movie` object, you could just do that by testing a public or internal `ParseJSON` recond on the `Movie` class.

However, since you are asking about mocking, here's a quick overview of one way you could write this test using a mock.  As it is written, `Movie_Information_Is_Loaded_Correctly()` looks like an integration test. To turn this into a unit test, you *could* mock out the web request the `Tomato` class makes. One way to do that would be to create a `ITomatoWebRequester` interface and pass that as a parameter to the `Tomato` class in the constructor. You could then mock the `ITomatoWebRequester` to return the web response you are expecting, and then you could test that the `Tomato` class properly parses that response.

The code could look something like this:

```
public class Tomato
{
    private readonly ITomatoWebRequester _webRequester;
    public Tomato(string uniqueID, ITomatoWebRequester webRequester)
    {
        _webRequester = webRequester;
    }

    public Movie FindMovieById(int movieID)
    {
        var responseJSON = _webRequester.GetMovieJSONByID(movieID);
        //The next line is what we want to unit test
        return Movie.Parse(responseJSON); 
    }
}

public interface ITomatoWebRequester
{
    string GetMovieJSONByID(int movieID);
}
```

To test, you could use a mocking framework like Moq to create a ITomatoWebRequester that will return a result you expect. To do that with Moq the following code should work:

```
[Test]
public void Movie_Information_Is_Loaded_Correctly()
{
    var mockWebRequester = new Moq.Mock<ITomatoWebRequester>();
    var myJson = "enter json response you want to use to test with here";
    mockWebRequester.Setup(a => a.GetMovieJSONByID(It.IsAny<int>())
        .Returns(myJson);

    Tomato tomato = new Tomato("t4qpkcsek5h6vgbsy8k4etxdd", 
        mockWebRequester.Object);
    var movie = tomato.FindMovieById(9818);
    movie.Title.ShouldEqual("Gone With The Wind");
}
```

The cool thing about the mock in this case is that you don't have to worry about all the hoops the actual `ITomatoWebRequester` has jump through to return the JSON it is supposed to return, you can just create a mock right in your test that returns exactly what you want.  Hopefully this answer serves as a decent intro to mocking. I would definitely suggest reading up on mocking frameworks to get a better feel for how the process works.

Answer (score 1):

Use Rhino.Mocks library and call Expectations where ever appropriate. Following is a sample mocking your movie object.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Rhino.Mocks;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Tomato
    {
        public Tomato(string t4qpkcsek5h6vgbsy8k4etxdd)
        {
           //
        }

        public virtual Movie FindMovieById(int i)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Movie
    {
        public string Title;

        public Movie( )
        {

        }

        public void FindMovieById(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class IndividualMovieTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Movie_Information_Is_Loaded_Correctly()
        {

            //Create Mock.
            Tomato tomato = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Tomato>("t4qpkcsek5h6vgbsy8k4etxdd");

            //Put expectations.
            tomato.Expect(t=>t.FindMovieById(0)).IgnoreArguments().Return(new Movie(){Title ="Gone With The Wind"});

            //Test logic.
            Movie movie = tomato.FindMovieById(9818);

            //Do Assertions.
            Assert.AreEqual("Gone With The Wind", movie.Title);

            //Verify expectations.
            tomato.VerifyAllExpectations();
        }
    }
}
```